# notepad++ delete first character in line with a certain word

Tags: notepad++

I would like to delete the first letter of any line where a certain word is. The specific word is "description" and I want to delete the semicolon, but only in the line where the word description appears. The other lines should remain untouched, unless the word description appears there as well.

Example:

```
;Version 21
;What is done here is the madness (description).txt;
;Version 22
;555 see above
```

Finished Version

```
;Version 21
What is done here is the madness (description).txt;
;Version 22
;555 see above
```

I have a text with about 10.000 lines and it would drive me crazy to check everything manually.
Is there any way to automate this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in NotePad++:

First search for "description": Ctrl-F, "description", ENTER

Move back to the top

Now record a macro: Macro | Start Recording

Press F3 (finds first occurrence of "description")

Press Home (moves cursor to beginning of line)

Press Delete (deletes first character)

Press Arrow Down (moves you off current line with "description")

Do Macro | Stop Recording

Now you have a macro recorded that does your desired action and you can do Macro | Playback (Ctrl-Shift-P) to have the previous steps replayed for the next occurrence of "description".

Comment: Thank you, that worked very well. You saved my evening.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression find and replace:

Open the Replace Dialog; on the Replace tab:

1. Find what: `^;(.*description.*)`
2. Replace with: `\1
3. Check "Regular expression in the "Search Mode" options
4. Click "Replace All" button.

How does it work?

The regular expression is composed of these parts:

- `^;` we match a `;` at the beginning of a line (via the `^` anchor)
- `.*description.*` matches something containing `description`
- by using parens, the match is stored in `\1` for reuse in the replacement
- by replacing only with `\1` we have effectively removed the `;` from each matching line